# Mostrar dados em um DataTable + JSF + Primefaces + CDI + ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, cdi

Fala ai pessoal!
Estou com um problema para popular um DataTable, estou usando JSf, CDI.

Eu acredito que o **nome** do **professor** está vindo normal pois ele é um objeto e o **aluno** é um `List`, mas nãos ei como resolver isso.
Eu estou tentando buscar o atributo `nome` na classe `Usuario` que pertence ao `Aluno` da seguinte forma:

**`GestaoProjetosBean`(meu bean de projetos) -> `Aluno.java`-> `Usuario.java` -> `nome`**

**E recebo o seguinte erro:**

> nov 12, 2017 6:42:24 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
>   GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/paginas/GestaoProjetos.xhtml]
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "usuario"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:150)
>       at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:67)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>       at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at org.primefaces.component.column.Column.renderChildren(Column.java:352)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:1051)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:999)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:907)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:854)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:814)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:290)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:252)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:87)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> nov 12, 2017 6:42:24 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
>   FATAL: JSF1073: java.lang.NumberFormatException obtido durante o processamento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=For input string: "usuario"
>   nov 12, 2017 6:42:24 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
>   FATAL: For input string: "usuario"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "usuario"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:150)
>       at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:67)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>       at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at org.primefaces.component.column.Column.renderChildren(Column.java:352)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:1051)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:999)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:907)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:854)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:814)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:290)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:252)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:87)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Essa é minha página que estou com problemas para trazer o nome do aluno do banco, pois o nome do professor está vindo normal.

**GestaoProjetos.xhtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  template="/WEB-INF/template/Layout.xhtml">
  
<ui:define name="titulo">
 <title>Gestão Projetos</title>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="conteudo">

 <f:metadata>
  <f:viewAction action="#{gestaoProjetosBean.todosProjetos}" />
 </f:metadata>

<p:dataTable id="projetosDataTable" value="#{gestaoProjetosBean.listaProjetos}"
   var="projeto" emptyMessage="Nenhuma informação a ser exibida"
   paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
   selectionMode="single" selection="#{gestaoProjetosBean.projeto}" rowKey="#{projeto.id}">
   
   <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="frm:toolbar" />
   
   <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="frm:toolbar" />
   
   <p:column headerText="Título" sortBy="#{projeto.titulo}">
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.titulo}" />
   </p:column>
   <!--AQUI O PROFESSOR VEM NORMAL -->
   <p:column headerText="Professor responsável">
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.professor.usuario.nome}" />
   </p:column>
   <!-- AQUI  É O PROBLEMA QUE NÃO VEM O NOME ALUNO -->
   <p:column headerText="Aluno" >
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.aluno.usuario.nome}" />
   </p:column>
    
  </p:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

**GestaoProjetosBean.java(Meu bean)**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class GestaoProjetosBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Projetos projetos;

    @Inject
    private FacesMessages messages;

    @Inject
    private CadastroProjetoService cadastroProjetoService;

    private List<Projeto> listaProjetos;

    private String termoPesquisa;

    private Projeto projeto;


    public void prepararNovoProjeto() {
        projeto = new Projeto();
        this.projeto.setUsuario(new Usuario());
        //this.projeto.setAluno(new Aluno());
        this.projeto.setProfessor(new Professor());

    }

    public void prepararEdicao() {

    }

    public void salvar() {
        cadastroProjetoService.salvar(projeto);

        atualizarRegistros();

        messages.info("Projeto salvo com sucesso!");

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList(
                "frm:monografiasDataTable", "frm:messages"));
    }

    public void excluir() {
        cadastroProjetoService.excluir(projeto);

        projeto = null;

        atualizarRegistros();

        messages.info("Projeto excluída com sucesso!");
    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        listaProjetos = projetos.pesquisar(termoPesquisa);

        if (listaProjetos.isEmpty()) {
            messages.info("Sua consulta não retornou registros.");
        }
    }

    public void todosProjetos() {
        listaProjetos = projetos.todas();
    }

    private void atualizarRegistros() {
        if (jaHouvePesquisa()) {
            pesquisar();
        } else {
            todosProjetos();
        }
    }

    private boolean jaHouvePesquisa() {
        return termoPesquisa != null && !"".equals(termoPesquisa);
    }

    public List<Projeto> getListaProjetos() {
        return listaProjetos;
    }

    public String getTermoPesquisa() {
        return termoPesquisa;
    }

    public void setTermoPesquisa(String termoPesquisa) {
        this.termoPesquisa = termoPesquisa;
    }

    public Projeto getProjeto() {
        return projeto;
    }

    public void setProjeto(Projeto projeto) {
        this.projeto = projeto;
    }

    public boolean isProjetoSeleciona() {
        return projeto != null && projeto.getId() != null;
    }
   }
```

**Aluno.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aluno")
public class Aluno implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", nullable = false)
private Usuario usuario;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Aluno other = (Aluno) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Aluno [id=" + id + "]";
}


}
```

**Usuario.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
private String nome;

@NotEmpty
@Email
@Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
private String email;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 8)
private Long matricula;

@NotEmpty
@Column(nullable = false, length = 8)
private String senha;

@Column(name = "ultimo_acessso")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date ultimoAcesso;

@Transient
private Professor professor;
@Transient
private List <Aluno> aluno;

public Usuario() {
    super();

}

public Usuario(Long matricula, String senha) {
    super();
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.senha = senha;

}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public Date getUltimoAcesso() {
    return ultimoAcesso;
}

public void setUltimoAcesso(Date ultimoAcesso) {
    this.ultimoAcesso = ultimoAcesso;
}

public Long getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(Long matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Professor getProfessor() {
    return professor;
}

public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}

public List<Aluno> getAluno() {
    return aluno;
}

public void setAluno(List<Aluno> aluno) {
    this.aluno = aluno;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Usuario [id=" + id + "]";
}

}
```

**Projeto.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projeto")
public class Projeto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(nullable = false, length = 120)
private String titulo;

@NotEmpty
@Column(nullable = false)
private String descricao;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "professor_id", nullable = false)
private Professor professor;


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="projeto_aluno", joinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="projeto_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="aluno_id")})
private List <Aluno> aluno;

@Transient
private Usuario usuario;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public Professor getProfessor() {
    return professor;
}

public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}

public List<Aluno> getAluno() {
    return aluno;
}

public void setAluno(List<Aluno> aluno) {
    this.aluno = aluno;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Projeto other = (Projeto) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Projeto [id=" + id + "]";
}
}
```

Comment: Qual a sua intenção? O erro é exatamente o que você falou, não existe o atributo `Aluno` na classe `Projeto`. Existe um `List` de `Aluno`.

Comment: Você quer mostrar todos os alunos desse projeto?

Comment: Opa Henrique blz!
Eu quero mostrar na linha do DataTable o título, professor e aluno que estão relacionados com esse projeto, logo eu não quero uma lista de alunos e sim o aluno relacionado a este projeto

Comment: mas você tem uma coleção, um list de alunos, e não só um.

Comment: Sim verdade, mas desculpa minha pergunta, que sou novo no desenvolvimento.
No mapeamento @manytomany só consegui fazer com o atributo 'aluno' como `List`, não consegui deixar ele como atributo do tipo `Aluno`, tem como ele ser `private Aluno aluno`?

Comment: cara, você tem que dar uma estudada em banco de dados e em jpa/hibernate. seu problema está na base das tecnologias que você esta utilizando.
Dá uma lida sobre relacionamentos em banco de dados e depois vê como o jpa provê esses relacionamentos com essas anotações `@OneTomany`, `@ManyToMany`........

Comment: Valeu Henrique!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse meu problema. Desculpa pela ignorância dessa pergunta boba de iniciante que o problema era bem simples de resolver, mas já tinha se matado de procurar e nada de resolver, por isso postei aqui.
Vou colocar aqui para ajudar algum novato como eu que cair nesse problema.

Resolvi modificando o meu `<h:outputText>` da seguinte forma:

```
        <p:column headerText="Aluno" >
            <h:outputText value="#{projeto.alunos[0].usuario.nome}" />
        </p:column>
```

Coloquei o `[0]`na propriedade `alunos` e ele recebeu o `nome` do `aluno` que eu não estava conseguindo pegar.Eu acho que o erro foi porque ele estava recebendo uma lista de `alunos`, mas eu só queria aquele `aluno` específico que estava relacionado ao `projeto` pelo `id`.

Quem quiser saber mais sobre, esse post me ajudou: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629067/showing-hibernate-jpa-results-in-jsf-datatable-causes-java-lang-numberformatexc